# Marmap: get shortest distance from point to isobath over water only

Tags: r, shortest-path

I am aware that I can use the dist2isobath function to extract the shortest distance from a point, e.g., a tide gauge location to an isobath (say the -200m) but that will **NOT** bypass land pixel. Is it possible to extract the shortest distance to the isobath but only "over water"? In other words, I am looking for an effective/approximate way to extract the width of the continental shelf at a particular point. I can only extract the distance only including over land pixels so far.

Comment: Does it help to filter out elevations > 0 m (in the case of the package's example data: `subset(nw.atlantic, V3 <=0)` before applying `as_bathy`?

Comment: Good point - thanks! I might try and check how this leads to different results (or not).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not something `marmap` can do at this time. You can either compute the shortest "great circle distance" between a point and an arbitrary isobath (as a route a bird or plane could take, hence crossing land if necessary), or you can compute the "least cost paths" between pairs of points avoiding land (or any relevant slice of depth/altitude, as fishes or marine mammals would do). At this time, it is not possible to combine these two very different approaches.

Comment: Thank you, Benoit! Your feedback is much appreciated.